# Problem with removing rows with .filter JS

Tags: javascript, mysql

```
var result_database = [
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 1 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 1 },
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 2 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 2 },
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 51, absentName: 'man3', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 51, absentName: 'man3', absentday: 4 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 3 }
]
```

So, `absent_date` and `absent_days` are to return the current day value, which for monday is 1.

```
const absent_date = new Date();
const absent_days = absent_date.getDay();
```

The rest:

```
let absent_remove = result_database.filter(item => item.absentday != absent_days);
const absent_duplicate = [...new Map(absent_remove.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()]
console.log("Absent Result", absent_duplicate);
```

So basically, `absent_remove` removes the database row if the `absentday` matches `absent_days`. I then get a bunch of duplicates which I solve with absent_duplicate, removing the duplicates. I'm left with these results down below.

```
Absent Result [
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 51, absentName: 'man3', absentday: 4 }
]
```

Man1 and Man2 are both absent on monday (1), but they are still in the query, the question is, how do I take them out? The final result should be man3 alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
res = [
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 1 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 1 },
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 2 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 2 },
  { id: 49, absentName: 'man1', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 51, absentName: 'man3', absentday: 3 },
  { id: 51, absentName: 'man3', absentday: 4 },
  { id: 50, absentName: 'man2', absentday: 3 }
]

answer = res.filter(x => !res.find(y => x.id == y.id && y.absentday == 1))
console.log(answer)
```

For every entry in your result we are only keeping it if there are no other entries with an absent day of '1'.

Comment: This works in the browser but displays an empty array when I use the terminal in VS code.

 absent_remove = result_database.filter(item1 => !result_database.find(item2 => item1.id == item2.id && item2.absentday == absent_days))

const absent_duplicate = [...new Map(absent_remove.map(item => [JSON.stringify(item.id), item])).values()]
    console.log(absent_duplicate)

Comment: Do you use the same data for result_database? Maybe there aren't any entries that match the criteria.

Comment: Yeah I do. Its a literal copy of the database. Not sure If it might be my statement, but I doubt it is. 

"SELECT id, developers.absentName, absentday FROM developers, absent WHERE absent.absentName=developers.absentName"

EDIT: If I remove the ! from res.find I get my results but I'd be back on square one.

Comment: Nevermind!!! It works, thanks a lot, It seems all of my DB values were on absentday=1, meaning they're all taken out of the query, hence it didn't give me results.